# concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor unreleased memory

Tags: python, concurrency, memory-leaks, concurrent.futures

I am currently using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` in my code to execute one of my code sections concurrently but after running it for a while, I can see a raise in memory consumption of my main process which just keep rising and doesn't get freed.

I'm currently using the `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` like that:

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool:
        processing_data = pool.map(handle_item, items_dict.values())

# Using the data in processing_data...
```

**I've seen some other people having issues the memory consumption using this module but other questions on SO that I've found were all using it a bit differently and It felt like it is not relevant for my case.**

If someone knows what I am doing wrong here or how I might fix that, I'll be grateful

Thanks everybody

#### Edit:

Here is an example code that reproduces the potential memory leak:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import time
import psutil
import random
import concurrent.futures

from memory_profiler import profile as mem_profile

p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

def do_magic(values):
    return None

@mem_profile
def foo():
    a = {i: chr(i) for i in range(1024)}
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool:
        proccessed_data = pool.map(do_magic, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])

def fooer():
    while True:
        foo()
        time.sleep(1)

fooer()
```